# Fixed size array in CLI layer

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have a function like this in C++

```
int GetValue(int iValue1, int(&iArrValue2)[8]);
```

I would like to have the same function in CLI layer. How can I do that in CLI header file?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in type that is a fixed-length array.

My recommendation would be to do the same thing that the .Net library does: Just take a plain array, and throw an `ArgumentException` if it's not the right length. For example, that's what the [`IPAddress` constructor](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/IPAddress.cs,966bd1c3b2dc55c7) does if you pass the wrong number of bytes.

If you must have this requirement, then you could create a custom type: Provide storage for 8 integers, and implement enough of the [Array class members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array) that one could use it as if it were an array. The issue with this is that you'll probably want to implement conversion to/from a plain int array, and then all you've done is move the length check & exception from your method into this conversion, and you've added the complication of a custom type.